# Query with table, temp table, subquery join issues

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, inner-join, temp-tables

I have a query where I create 2 temp tables at the start, then I query an existing table in my DB and join this table to a subquery, and then lastly join to 1 of the temp tables.  When i do this I get an error that the key I'm joining on from the existing table cannot be bound.  What's weird is if I take out all references to the subquery and leave just the query with the existing table and the temp table it joins fine, and also if I joint the existing table to just the sub suery it works just fine.

But when I try to put all 3 together it gives the me the "the multi-part identified z.[currnecy key] cannot be bound", which seems an odd error since this key is in an existing table and joins just fine to a temp table or sub query alone, but not both together.

I know about issues with joining on sub queries, but in this situation it seems that the issue seems to be with joining to sub queries and temp tables in the same query, which I'm not sure how to work around.

Code is below.

```
declare @tmpFx table (currency_key int, effective_date_key int, expiration_date_key int, to_usd float, from_usd float ) --primary key (currency_key, date_key))
    insert into @tmpFx(currency_key, effective_date_key, expiration_date_key, to_usd, from_usd)
    select [currency key], cast(convert(char(8),[effective date],112) as int), cast(convert(char(8),[expiration date],112) as int), [to usd], [from usd]
    from v_fx --where [effective date] >= @beginDate

declare @fixedFx table (currency_key int, to_usd float, from_usd float primary key (currency_key))
    insert into @fixedFx(currency_key, to_usd, from_usd)
    select [currency key], [to usd], [from usd] 
    from v_fx where [effective date] = '2012-01-01'

select z.[currency key], --stat_fx.to_usd to_usd, stat_fx.from_usd from_usd, --q.*,-- 
stat_usd_amt2 = case when z.[currency key] = 100001 then q.orig_amt else 0 end --sum(q.orig_amt * stat_fx.to_usd)
from [dim country] z,
(select b.country_key, a.currency_key, a.data_type_key, sum(a.amount) orig_amt,
    sum(a.amount * stat_fx.to_usd) stat_usd_amt, 
    sum((a.amount * stat_fx.to_usd) * stat_fx.from_usd) home_curr_amt 
    from tbl_cohort a 
    inner join tbl_management_code b on a.management_code = b.management_code
    left outer join @tmpFx stat_fx on a.currency_key = stat_fx.currency_key
    where a.data_type_key = 1
    and a.date_key > 20111231
    group by b.country_key, a.currency_key, a.data_type_key) q
inner join @tmpFx stat_fx on z.[currency key] = stat_fx.currency_key
where q.[country_key]= z.[country key]
```

Comment: Part of the problem here might be that you're mixing two different join syntaxes which makes it quite hard to understand. You're using ANSI standard `INNER` and `LEFT` joins for some but the inline view with alias `q` is joined as part of a comma separated list of tables.

Comment: also, can you set up a representative example on SQL Fiddle? It's hard to spot the problem when we don't know what the tables are.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you are mixing join formats between the old style and new style (as ninesided suggested). I was able to mock up a similar issue with my own data and got the same error about unbound identifiers. Give the following a try instead.

```
declare @tmpFx table (currency_key int, effective_date_key int, expiration_date_key int, to_usd float, from_usd float)
    insert into @tmpFx(currency_key, effective_date_key, expiration_date_key, to_usd, from_usd)
    select [currency key], cast(convert(char(8),[effective date],112) as int), cast(convert(char(8),[expiration date],112) as int), [to usd], [from usd]
    from v_fx

declare @fixedFx table (currency_key int, to_usd float, from_usd float primary key (currency_key))
    insert into @fixedFx(currency_key, to_usd, from_usd)
    select [currency key], [to usd], [from usd] 
    from v_fx where [effective date] = '2012-01-01'

select z.[currency key], 
    case when z.[currency key] = 100001 then q.orig_amt else 0 end AS stat_usd_amt2
from [dim country] z
JOIN (
    select b.country_key, a.currency_key, a.data_type_key, sum(a.amount) AS orig_amt,
    sum(a.amount * stat_fx.to_usd) as stat_usd_amt, 
    sum((a.amount * stat_fx.to_usd) * stat_fx.from_usd) as home_curr_amt 
    from tbl_cohort a 
    join tbl_management_code b
        on a.management_code = b.management_code
    left join @tmpFx stat_fx
        on a.currency_key = stat_fx.currency_key
    where a.data_type_key = 1
      and a.date_key > 20111231
    group by b.country_key, a.currency_key, a.data_type_key
) q
    ON q.[country_key] = z.[country_key]
join @tmpFx stat_fx 
    on z.[currency key] = stat_fx.currency_key
```

And while I've left in your second temp table (@fixedFx), you may want to remove it if you don't have plans on using its data at all.